# Does aws ecs distributed load testing support jmeter mqtt sampler

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, mqtt, jmeter-plugins, mosquitto

I am performing jmeter distributed load testing, I have been trying to setup aws ecs containers for load testing of mosquitto mqtt.

Does aws distributed load testing support jmeter mqtt sampler plugin
[mqtt-jmeter](https://github.com/xmeter-net/mqtt-jmeter) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is no. aws distriubted testiong work only with http.

Answer (score 1):

If your test is using any [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - you will need to install the plugin on:

- master machine
- and all the slave machines

So amend your container building scripts in order to include the plugin and all its dependencies and do this for both master and slave. [JMeter Plugins Manager can be executed as a command-line tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)

The same applies to any test data like CSV files used in [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)

You may find [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker) article interesting and get some more ideas on preparing your containers